# ms access 2013 missing entries after export to csv/tab file with delimiter

Tags: ms-access, export-to-csv, missing-data

I would like to export an Access table to a CSV or TAB file but every time I run the export (using the built-in export Tools/buttons in the 'External Data' tab of the ribbon), some entries are missing (roughly -10%).

Any clue as to where this might originate from?

Thank you :)

Comment: Another weird fact: when asking for an export without headers, the number of exported entries is larger. (I hope it contains the full set of data? ...FYI: I need to check this because some entries are interlaced in the export).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is happening and/or why this is happening but a work-around that allowed me to retrieve all my data was to **export data from Access without headers**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I would check unsupported character thing. Probably in your data has some. And you need to deal with them somehow. I would google something like "MS ACCESS EXPORT BOM HANDLING". I would try to export data example as plain text and check it.